# class methods/array in activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a list from a class' attributes

I'm new with ruby- i have an activerecord class called fixture and what an array of "Home Team", "Draw", "Away team", where home team and away team are both fields in the Fixture table

I have come up with the following code sticking it in the Fixture class- how do access the values of the class?

```
self.fix_list = [home_team.title, "Draw", away_team.title]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that "Fixture" is a pretty bad name for a model. Anyways:

```
class Fixture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :home_team, :class_name => "Team", :foreign_key => "home_team_id"
  belongs_to :away_team, :class_name => "Team", :foreign_key => "away_team_id"
  named_scope :with_team, lambda { |team_id| { :conditions => ['(home_team_id = ? 
    or away_team_id = ?)', team_id, team_id]} }

  def fix_list
    [home_team.title, "Draw", away_team.title]
  end
end

class Team < ActiveRecord:Base
  def fixtures
    Fixture.with_team(id)
  end
end
```

Of course, in your migration for the "fixtures" table, you need to create the columns named `home_team_id` and `away_team_id`.

Edit: I just notices that my initial `has_many` association in `Team` is useless. That `named_scope` is untested and I'm going to bed now!

Comment: Yes, someone pointed it out to me before but no problems have arisen so far, thanks for that

Comment: Please note that I edited the above posting - I was tired, so I used symbol names in the class and foreign key names, which is wrong.